# A question about centralizer of a vectors in the positive Weyl chamber.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a compact Lie group $K$, and a maximal torus $T\leq K$, and choose a positive Weyl chamber $\mathfrak t^*_+\subset \mathfrak k^*$. Then $\mathfrak t^*_+$ can be decomposed into disjoint open faces, $\mathfrak t^*_+=\sqcup_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\sigma$. The question is to prove $K_\sigma$ is well-defined as the centralizer of any $\xi\in\sigma$, i.e. for any $\xi,\xi'\in\sigma$, $K_\xi=K_{\xi'}$.

This is what I read from *Symplectic Implosion*, [Guillemin, Jeffrey, Sjamaar 's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00031-002-0009-y) (this can be found after definition 2.1).